# How to add Enterprise resource to Project Online using Powershell. Stuck with no luck

Tags: powershell, csom

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Users\klkc510\Downloads\DeleteResources\bin\Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Users\klkc510\Downloads\DeleteResources\bin\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Users\klkc510\Downloads\DeleteResources\bin\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'

$pwaPath = ""
$projContext = New-Object Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.ProjectContext($pwapath)
$UserName= ""
$Password = ""


$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))  
$projContext.Credentials = $credentials  

$projContext.Load($projContext.EnterpriseResources)
$projContext.ExecuteQuery()  
$erp = $projContext.EnterpriseResources
$enterprise_resourceid = [Guid]::NewGuid()
$resname = "Test"
$body = {parameters:{'Id:$enterprise_resourceid"",Name:$resname}}
$erp.Add.$body
Write-Host("Deleted Resource: " +  $body.Id)
$erp.Update()
$projContext.ExecuteQuery()
$projContext.Load($projContext.EnterpriseResources)
```